# Consistent updates with Powershell to Azure table storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage

Azure storage tables implement Etag which I would like to use to confirm that I am updating the latest entry to avoid overwriting my changes when there are multiple updates happening. However, I cannot figure out how can I use this with the AzTable PS module as it seems to just overwrite and does not care about the Etag. Can I somehow make AzTable module to use Etag or any other way to achieve this in Powershell?

I am currently following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell and bumped into this problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written.

Comment: Can you share the issue what you are exactly faced. so that community will help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the easiest way to achieve this is to change the 'InsertOrMerge' to 'Merge' in the 'Update-AzTableRow'-function https://github.com/paulomarquesc/AzureRmStorageTable/blob/master/AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1#L696